# Laravel Api Request Firing Twice on Production Server

Tags: php, angular, laravel, ionic-framework

Im using Ionic as my apps development and laravel as the server. I recently moved my laravel project from localhost to production VPS Server. At localhost, my API requests are fine. But when i moved the project to VPS Server, the request firing twice at one time.

What i've done =

1. Re-Upload the project from localhost to vps server (including database)
2. Re-Upload the project using git.
3. Cleared route, view, cache, config (laravel cache)

But nothing change, the problem still occur.

```
{\"data\":[{\"id\":53,\"name\":\"Rumah\",\"user_id\":2,\"receipent\":\"John Doe\",\"receipent_phone\":\"62812345678\",\"address\":\"Los Angeles\",\"district\":\"Bengkong, Batam, Kepulauan Riau\",\"district_id\":5}]}"}} 
[2020-07-10 20:59:01] local.INFO: app.requests {"request":[],"method":"DELETE","response":{"Illuminate\\Http\\JsonResponse":"HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, Content-Type, X-Token-Auth, Authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:  *
Cache-Control:                no-cache, private
Content-Type:                 application/json
Date:                         Fri, 10 Jul 2020 13:59:01 GMT
X-Ratelimit-Limit:            120
X-Ratelimit-Remaining:        115

{\"message\":\"Sukses menghapus data\"}"}} 
[2020-07-10 20:59:01] local.INFO: app.requests {"request":[],"method":"DELETE","response":{"Illuminate\\Http\\JsonResponse":"HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, Content-Type, X-Token-Auth, Authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:  *
Cache-Control:                no-cache, private
Content-Type:                 application/json
Date:                         Fri, 10 Jul 2020 13:59:01 GMT
X-Ratelimit-Limit:            120
X-Ratelimit-Remaining:        114

{\"message\":\"No data\"}"}}
```

Above are the Logging details from my laravel project about the API incoming request on VPS server. You can see the request Time are the same. But, when im using Postman, the request is normal, like when i'm using localhost I'm new to this. any help would be appreciated, Thank you.

Comment: Never dealt with VPS, but is the first request an OPTIONS request, i.e, a pre-flight request?

Comment: i've edited the question @vivek_23, i added method detail in the logging. I also thought it was OPTIONS for CORS, but the method not showing OPTIONS.

Comment: That’s really strange... I don’t think it’s the same issue, but I had issues in the past with two api requests being sent when using incognito mode in a browser.

Comment: @HendryPutra Are you checking from the browser?

Comment: Im using ionic app. so yes. requesting from the browser @vivek_23, but when im using postman, the request only come once, i mean its normal (that's what im looking for)

Comment: @HendryPutra Then it's mostly about OPTIONS request.

Comment: @HendryPutra Build the android version of the app and check from the app installed in the mobile, it should work smoothly.

Comment: @vivek_23 i've already build the ionic android version app and used it. sorry, still no change.

Comment: Can you add a custom header from ionic while making the request?

Comment: what header should i add? @vivek_23

Comment: Like say test-header:test from client side

Comment: okay, added, https://imgur.com/qiQctAh --> that's the freflight request header @vivek_23

Comment: Don't use `Accept`. Put anything else, like `test-header`. Also, test this in an actual device and not on emulator.

Comment: okay, i'll inform the result. but i have some useful information! when i disabled security web at chrome, the apps going well as i expected, the request sent 1 time and received by server 1 time too. maybe CORS prob? @vivek_23

Comment: Yes, I suspect it's a CORS issue, but anyway, disabling security is just a workaround. I don't feel you would need CORS when you test this Android app on a real device.

Comment: i tried build the app and tested it on my Android device, but the problem still remain. i've also added custom header that you asked https://imgur.com/a/rfveW5H, i don't know how to get the request detail in Android, but i think it would be the same as when im using browser. @vivek_23